# Java Hdd graphical representation

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Hi I'm working on a hard drive simulation in java and I want to be able to represent fragmentation in any given drive(represented as a series of Objects Hashmaps,Arrays etc) Something like the bars in xp's old fragmentation tool [XP toolbar](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=tDD&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=xp+defragment+tool&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k&biw=1366&bih=632&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=5FsnUaXoHKWM0wX_1YDwCw). I was thinking of a bar or pie chart from google i have gleamed that swing may be my best option? Could anyone give any pointers how I might go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for a potentially huge number of [possible renderings](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). [Here's a page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm) with a large number of samples, including code.

Comment: Additional guidance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info); [`XYBlockRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBlockRenderer.html) seems apropos.

Answer (score 0):

JFreeChart is usually the best choice for charting in Swing applications. There are some other open-source libraries as well. See the last question on [this](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html) page.

However, if you need some custom features, you may need to do some custom rendering in `Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 0):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) might be a solution for bar or piecharts, but If you just need a simple stacked bar, I would indeed recommend overwriting a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) from the swing library. That will be very easy.

If you need some more graphs and plots and stuff anyway, definitely have a look at JFreeChart, it's great.